# Looking for a word or idiom that describe someone whose mood changes constantly

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, idiom-requests, epithet-requests, psychology

As the title says, I'm looking for a word or idiom to describe a person whose  mood changes regularly in a very short time and you never know what's going on in his head.

Some examples:

> He can be very optimistic about the world and suddenly being extremely pessimistic after seeing some bad news in social media.
>
> He can be very positive about dating a nice girl, yet being nervous because he "smells" something's wrong in the way she texts him.
>
> He reckons for very long time about quitting his job and seem to be very determined. Once again,  a little "maybe" occurs in his head and he change his mind suddenly.

Comment: Wouldn't moody, changeable, unpredictable, uncertain  work? noun or adjective? It seems a broad question with so many answers.

Comment: For me, even *alive* (lively) or *human* might work just fine as a synonym for someone with changeable moods and/or emotions. It is broad, because it's a judgment call.

Comment: My suggestions: I believe there are plenty of synonyms for an uncertain person. (personally, the one I like is *inconstant*). And for your idiom-request I suggest: [**A change of heart**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/change+of+heart). "A change in one's opinion or feelings on a matter". E.g. '*She was going to take that job offer in California, but after thinking about how much she would miss her friends and family in Delaware, she had a change of heart.*'
Note that it is used usually (not always) from a negative to a positive position.

Comment: Mercurial would work here.

Answer (score 2):

What comes to mind would be the term **bipolar**.

The individual described in the question would be referred to as suffering **bipolar disorder**, or would simply be referred to as **bipolar**.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_disorder) defines **bipolar disorder** as:

> Bipolar disorder, previously known as manic depression, is a mental disorder that causes periods of depression and periods of abnormally elevated mood.[...]During mania, an individual behaves or feels abnormally energetic, happy, or irritable. [...] During periods of depression, there may be crying, a negative outlook on life, and poor eye contact with others.....

---

<sub>Alternatively, the individual can be classified as having **mood swings** (which is a symptom of bipolar disorder). For more information, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mood_swing)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

a **loose cannon** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/loose+cannon)

one who has the propensity to act **unpredictably** or to lose their temper very quickly

Answer (score 1):

Let's be honest, [**unpredictable**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unpredictable), while a simple word, is one that fits your two examples just perfectly:

> likely to change suddenly and without reason and therefore not able to be predicted

Another possible suggestion could be the adjective [**volatile**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/volatile):

> If someone is volatile, their mood often changes quickly (the idea is that they can quickly become angry).
>
> Example: *He had a volatile temper and couldn't have been easy to live with.*

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is not a diagnosis**, but the symptoms as you describe them might correspond with **borderline personality disorder**. According to [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/borderline%20personality%20disorder):

> a disordered behavior pattern that has an onset during adolescence or early adulthood and that is **marked by unstable, intense emotions and mood with symptoms including instability in interpersonal relationships and self-image, fears of abandonment, and impulsive or unpredictable behavior**

Attribution: "Borderline Personality Disorder." Merriam-Webster. Accessed April 08, 2018. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/borderline personality disorder.