# What's a good word to describe someone who is prone to sudden changes of mood?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives

I'm looking for an adjective, preferably a kind of "fancy" one that I can use to describe a character who has frequent changes of mood, often in a very sudden or extreme way. It also causes problems for people around her.

It's not 'fickle', by the way, which describes a person who had frequent changes of opinion.

An example sentence would be:

> She was a ___ woman, a woman who was prone to quick outbursts and fiery changes of mood.

Comment: Related I think? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/440645/looking-for-a-word-or-idiom-that-describe-someone-whose-mood-changes-constantly One of the answers over there is "bipolar", which I was thinking about

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I suggest [**volatile**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/volatile)

> likely to change suddenly and unexpectedly, especially by getting worse

or

[**capricious**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/capricious)

> showing sudden changes in attitude or behaviour
> changing suddenly and quickly

or

[**erratic**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/erratic)

> moving or behaving in a way that is not regular, certain, or expected

She was a volatile / capricious / erratic woman, a woman who was prone to quick outbursts and fiery changes of mood.

Comment: It would have been better to write 3 answers, so the different words could be voted separately. I only voted for "capricious". I would not vote for the others.

Comment: I like volatile.

Comment: All three of these suggestions would work, and my order of preference for them matches the answer (IOW, "volatile" is the best match, "capricious" is 2nd best, and "erratic", while still workable, is not the best choice).

Comment: Volatile and erratic seem to fit. Capricious carries an implication that they’re doing it on purpose.

Answer (score 37):

Perhaps *mercurial*.  My dictionary (Chambers 13 edn) includes

> active, sprightly, often changing

in its definition of the word.

In former times a woman, such as in the example sentence, might be described as *flighty*, which the same dictionary defines as

> swift (*Shakesp*), fanciful, changeable, giddy-minded, irresponsible,
> flirtatious

Comment: *Mercurial* is part of the vocabulary of the old four-humor psychology--which, as this term itself hints, had defined correspondences with astrology. The mercurial temperament was one in which various of the humors prevailed at various times, and so would be liable to sudden and unpredictable shifts.

Comment: This is the word. But I think you did not select the best definition in the answer. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/mercurial

Comment: @Damila — Yes, I would upvote this answer if the second offering (*flighty*) were removed and a better definition for *mercurial* sourced. e.g. *OED*: **IV.** Extended uses. **7.** Of a person: having a lively, volatile, or restless nature; liable to sudden and unpredictable changes of mind or mood; quick-witted, imaginative.

Answer (score 19):

> **moody** adjective
> 2
> : subject to moods : TEMPERAMENTAL
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moody)

Answer (score 9):

You could call such a person *tempestuous*, if by 'fancy' you mean 'literary':

> characterized by strong and turbulent or conflicting emotion ([Oxford Languages)](https://www.google.com/search?q=tempestuous%20define)
>
> 1] of, involving, or like a tempest 2] violent; turbulent ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/tempestuous))

Another good word is *temperamental*:

> marked by excessive sensitivity and impulsive mood changes...unpredictable in behavior or performance ([Merriam-Webster](http://onelook.com/reverse-dictionary.shtml?s=temperamental))

From those definitions, *[turbulent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/turbulent)* also works. So does *[fiery](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fiery)*, which you used, and  [hot-headed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hotheaded), although the latter isn't quite so elevated.

Answer (score 3):

[impetuous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impetuous) [M-W]

> marked by impulsive [vehemence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vehemence) or passion
> an *impetuous* temperament

Example sentence:

> She was an *impetuous* woman, a woman who was prone to quick outbursts
> and fiery changes of mood.

Answer (score 2):

Since a comment has mentioned the temperaments, the classical temperament of someone who is prone to outbursts and *fiery* changes of mood is **choleric**. But cholerics are also stubborn.

On the other hand, the temperament that is flighty and capricious is **sanguine**.

Comment: Factually accurate.  But "choleric" is not a word that anyone's used for a very long time.  It's not fancy, it's verging on archaic, and only a tiny minority would even know the word.  And in spite of its origin with classical temperaments, the generally-understood meaning of "sanguine" is "cheerfully optimistic", which does not fit with the OP's description.

Comment: @Graham I don’t think of _choleric_ as being archaic at all – a bit old-fashioned, perhaps, but certainly not archaic. But it doesn’t in my experience mean capricious or mercurial – it just means bad-tempered, irritable, irascible. It doesn’t relate to mood swings, but to just being generally irritated and grumpy and given to angry outbursts.

Comment: @Graham  You don't know my colleagues.  The temperaments are a frequently discussed topic!   The thing is the question asks for someone with sudden changes of mood (a sanguine characteristic) but the example describes firey outburst (a choleric characteristic)   It's clear that "flighty/mercurial" wouldn't fit the example.

Answer (score 1):

The word you want really is: "temperamental". My Webster's defines this term as: "marked by excessive sensitivity and impulsive changes of mood".  But if you are writing fiction, you might want to have a bit more fun, and try "female", the word that immediately came to mind, when I read your request.  You could create a sentence that then has a poetic trick, perhaps like: "She was a very female kind of woman - prone to quick changes of mood, suggesting a fiery temperament, that could be seen in the way her eyes flashed as we spoke."   The term "female kind of woman" might seem obviously silly, but depending on the context of your story, and the feeling you want to create in the mind of your reader, it might work.  English is lovely language, which sometimes works even better when it's rules are broken, and the technical meaning is scrambled just a bit.  Good luck with your story.